# PHP MYSQL configuration for handling case insensivity in table names

Tags: php, mysql, case-sensitive, rds

In my application database some of the tables are names in lowercase letters and some are in upper case. I want to male my database to run queries via PHP without considering the case of tables.

On amazon RDS instance I have set the value of lower_case_table_names=1 for making my database case insensitive.

When I run the query in HeidiSQL or Phpmyadmin with lower case table names then I am able to run the queries. But when I run the same queries via PHP file, the query does not runs and table name does not exist error is shown.

Is there any other setting in PHP side that I needs to do?

Comment: what is your operating system windows or linux?

Comment: Did the services restart, after making the configuration change ?

Comment: or you could just normalize the case of your names and bypass the problem...

Comment: @GoudaElalfy Linux OS

Comment: @andre3wap Yes I restart the services after making those config changes, after that I am able to run queries in HeidiSQL with any case either lower or upper.

Comment: Are you using PDO or mysqli?  (or mysql) for your dbms interface in php?

Comment: Ollie I am using mysql

Comment: could you post an example of the PHP code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

update your mysql configuration file:  /etc/mysql/my.cnf
to set

```
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

then restart mysql

after setting your lower_case_table_names = 1, you should import your database then drop it and recreate again.

Comment: In my.cnf this setting is already there, i.e lower_case_table_names = 1